# Physical application/interpretation of union and intersection (case example)

Tags: probability

> Suppose that one card is to be selected from a deck of 20 cards that contains 10 red cards numbered from 1 to 10 and 10 blue cards numbered from 1 to 10.  Let A be the event that a card with an even number is selected, let B be the event that a blue card is selected, and let C be the event that a card with a number less than 5 is selected.   Describe the sample space S and describe each of the following events both in words and as as a subset of S:
>
> a.  $A \cap B \cap C$
>
> b.  $B \cap C'$
>
> c.  $A \cup B \cup C$
>
> d.  $A \cap (B \cup C)$
>
> e.  $A' \cap B' \cap C'$

So as a summary:

A=Even # card

B= Blue card

C= Card # < 5 so its {1,2,3,4}

> a.  even, blue card is selected and its value is less than 5 so its either 2 or 4.
>
> b.  blue card selected and its value is 5,6,7,8,9 or 10.
>
> e.  odd, red card, whose value is greater than or equal to 5 so its value is 5,7 or 9.

Now the union questions throw me off.  When you say $A \cup B$, this means A alone, B alone, or BOTH.

So for part (c), I thought it would mean the following:  Either odd or even, blue or red, and number including 1-10.  But this isn't right.

I'm not sure how to interpret (d) either.  Can someone please step by step explain the thought process to interpret (c) and (d)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element is part of the union of the sets $A_1,A_2...A_n$ if it's part of at least one of the sets $A_1,A_2...A_n$

So in the case $c)$ we have:

In order a card to be part of the subset $S = A \cup B \cup C$ it need to be part in at least one of the sets $A,B,C$

This means that the subset S contains every even number card (because every even numberd card is part of the set A), every blue card (every blue card is part of the set B) and every card with number smaller than 5 (because such card is part of the set C).

This means that every card except for $5RED$,$7RED$ and $9RED$ is part of the subset S.

And for $d)$ we have:

Let $S_1$ = $B \cup C$. Now we now that every blue card and every red card with number smaller than 5 is part of $S_1$. Now let $S = A \cap S_1$. We need to find every even numbered card in the subset $S_1$. So the subset $S$ consists of blue cards with number $2,4,6,8,10$ and red cards with number $2,4$

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.  I still don't understand your explanation.  I get that it must be in at least one of the sets A, B, and C, but I don't see how its every card except 5,7, and 9 red.  Can you please break it down more?

Comment: I guess essentially all your doing is the following:  $(A \cap B \cap C)=1-(A \cap B \cap C)' $ and listing $(A \cap B \cap C)'$

Comment: It more like $(A \cup B \cup C) = 1 - \overline{(A \cup B \cup C)}$. And then I'm listing the items that are not included, because there are only 3 of them

Answer (score 1):

For (c), you have cards which are either even, blue, or numbered less than 5;  so the only cards which do NOT satisfy this property are red cards which are odd and numbered 5, ..., 10.  Therefore this gives all cards EXCEPT red cards numbered 5, 7, or 9.

For (d), you have cards which are even and also are either blue or numbered 1,...,4.  This is the same as all blue even cards AND all red cards numbered 2 or 4.